# fastapi return response to index.html

Tags: javascript, python, html, fastapi

I'm using Fastapi as interface for other api built on nodejs ([baileys-api](https://github.com/ookamiiixd/baileys-api))

currently i have textfield [senderID], when click generate QR button , it will take the value from senderID to create QR code.

the api take input string as sender id.

```
# send senderID to baileys-api to get qr code
urlQr = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sessions/add"

payload=f"id={senderID}&isLegacy=false"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.request("POST", urlQr, headers=headers, data=payload)
# save json response to python
response = json.loads(response.text)
```

and will give response as json

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "QR code received, please scan the QR code.",
"data": {
    "qr": "data:image/png;base64,encodedCodexxxxxx"
}
```

Currently I have 2 files main.py as server and index.html

**main.py**

```
import qrcode
from PIL import Image
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import requests
import uvicorn
import json

# import logger
import logging

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
# 
@app.get("/sender")
def sender(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

@app.post("/generateQR")
# make function to generate QR code, parse senderID value and return QR code
def generateQR(senderID: str = Form()):

    # senderID = request.form_data["senderID"]
    

    # send senderID to baileys-api to get qr code
    urlQr = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sessions/add"

    payload=f"id={senderID}&isLegacy=false"
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", urlQr, headers=headers, data=payload)
    # save json response to python
    response = json.loads(response.text)

    # save json response to variable
    qr = response["data"]["qr"]
    status = response["success"] 
    message = response["message"] #MESSAGE SUCCESSFULLY SENT TO INDEX.HTML

    # return qr to index.html
    return {"qrCode": qr, "status": status, "message": message}


# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=7000)
```

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- create nice header -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>
                    Add new Whatsapp Sender
                </h1>
                <p> contoh sender id : 6013310276 </p>
            </div>
      

        <div class="form-outline">
            <label class="form-label" for="senderID">Sender ID</label>
            <input type="text" id="senderID" class="form-control" />
            
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="generateQR()"> Generate Qr Code ! </button>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    function generateQR() {
        var senderID = document.getElementById("senderID").value;
        var formData = new FormData();
        var endpoint = '/generateQR';
        if (senderID == "") {
            swal("Oops...", "Sender ID Can't be empty!", "error");
        } else {    
            formData.append('senderID', senderID);
            $.ajax({
                url: endpoint,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.status == "true") { //data.status not returned from main.py
                        swal("Success!", data.status, "success");
                        // // 
                        // // show qr code image
                        // //
                       
                        

                        // var qrCode = data.qrCode;
                        // var qrCodeImage = document.createElement("img");
                        // qrCodeImage.src = qrCode;
                        // qrCodeImage.style.width = "200px";
                        // qrCodeImage.style.height = "200px";
                        // qrCodeImage.style.margin = "10px";
                        // document.body.appendChild(qrCodeImage);

                    } else {
                        swal("Oops...", data.message, "error"); //data.message return from main.py
                    }
                }
            });           
            
        }
    }



    
  </script>
```

the problem is :

It seems it can't return QR image and status value but it can return message value

So how to fix the code so QR code img can appear on index.html

**thanks**

[I would like qr code appear on this page after generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkGmK.png)

Comment: Have you checked in your browser's development tools what the response from your API _actually_ is? Since you're comparing against the string `true`, that comparison might fail. Check the actual output and start from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data.status == "true") { 
                    swal("Success!", data.status, "success");
```

change to :

```
if (data.status) { 
                    swal("Success!", data.message, "success");
```

true != "true"